# Removing text fields with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I did an add and remove textbox fields with jQuery and the add function is working fine, but the remove function is causing a problem. Can't remove a field after adding it. I tried to detect the error behind it but cannot find any.

Please I need fresh eyes to help me detect where I went wrong.
Below is the code:

```js
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Variables
  var hello = '<div id="p"><div class="row"><div id="p" class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="make" class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="make" class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="model" class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name ="serial" class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-1"><span id="remove" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><b> - </b></span></div><br><br></div></div>';
 
  // Add rows to the form
  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("#fields").append(hello); 
  });
 
  // Remove rows from the form
  $("#fields").on('click', '#remove', function() {
    $(this).parent('#p').remove(); 
  });
   
  // Populate values from the first row
 
});

</script>
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 7%;" >
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-10 col-sm-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form class="form" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group floating-label">
                            <input readonly type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="large4" >
                            <label for="large4">Request Title</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group floating-label">
                            <input readonly type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="default4">
                            <label for="default4">Objective of Request</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group floating-label">
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                    <b>Items</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                                    <b>Specs (if any)</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                                    <b>Quantity</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                                    <b>Amount</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="fields" class="form-group floating-label">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" name="make" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="text" name="make" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" name="model" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" name ="serial" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                    <a href="#" id="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><b> + </b></a>
                                </div>
                                <br><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-actionbar">
                            <div class="card-actionbar-row">
                                <br><br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary ink-reaction">SUBMIT</button>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end .card-actionbar -->
                    </form>
                </div><!--end .card-body -->
            </div><!--end .card -->
        </div><!--end .col -->
    </div><!--end .row -->
</div>

<!-- END SIZES -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your #remove element to `<a href="#" id="remove" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><b> - </b></a>` .

And change your remove function to the following. Ensure you use closest instead of parent.

```
$("#fields").on('click', '#remove', function(){
        $(this).closest('#p').remove(); 
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line:

```
$(this).parent('#p').remove();
```

From [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/parent/):

> ... the parent() method traverses to the **immediate** parent of each of these elements ...

You should use `.closest()` method. From [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and **traversing up through its
>   ancestors** in the DOM tree.

So your code should look like that:

```
$(this).closest('#p').remove();
```

And one more note. I think it is not the best practice to use id's  for elements that possibly may have duplicates with the same id. That may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/1aurfeox/1/

You dont need to create a variable with string. you can clone first existing element then work on it to create removable row.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Variables
    var hello = $("div#fields .row").clone();
    hello.find("#add").parent().html('<a href="#" id="remove" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><b> - </b></a>');
    //Add rows to the form
    $("#add").click(function() {
      $("#fields").append(hello.clone());
      $("#remove").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".row").remove();
      });
    });
  });
```